# Installation failed due to invalid APK file

Tags: android, eclipse

I can not debug my app, this problem arises after changing my rom.
probe back to the original rom and it works fine, the problem is with this rom

```
[2013-08-29 10:22:47 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]
[2013-08-29 10:22:47 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Android Launch!
[2013-08-29 10:22:47 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-29 10:22:47 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Performing com.androidbegin.sidemenutabstutorial.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-08-29 10:22:48 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'TA32402UGY'
[2013-08-29 10:22:48 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Uploading SideMenuTabsTutorial.apk onto device 'TA32402UGY'
[2013-08-29 10:22:49 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Installing SideMenuTabsTutorial.apk...
[2013-08-29 10:22:50 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-08-29 10:22:50 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-08-29 10:22:50 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Launch canceled!
```

------------------ Edit --------------------

I gave this to clean the project, but before I change the ROM everything worked well without problems

```
[2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Versions found are:
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Path: C:\Users\luis\workspace\ABS\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    Length: 271754
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Path: C:\Users\luis\workspace\SideMenuTabsTutorial\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    Length: 556198
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
    [2013-08-29 11:04:57 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Versions found are:
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Path: C:\Users\luis\workspace\ABS\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    Length: 271754
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Path: C:\Users\luis\workspace\SideMenuTabsTutorial\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    Length: 556198
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial]    SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
    [2013-08-29 11:05:08 - SideMenuTabsTutorial] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: What is the logcat output?

Comment: Contact the rom developer. It's not a programming question.

Comment: `: E/(): Device disconnected `

Comment: could it be that you already have the apk installed on your device?

If so, try to uninstall it first.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cleaning` the project.

You may be missing `libs` folder if you are importing an example file from some library.

Also when you clean the project, you can check the `problem` window. It shows why or what error it is.

Answer (score 0):

delete support-v4 from your library folder.

ther is already one support exist in the external library u have added .